# Android Activity Force Close Issue

Tags: android, progressdialog, logcat

`enter code here`I am trying to put a Progress Dialog in my Android application and I am having a little trouble with it. I am new to Android so I am following this tutorial:
http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-make-a-progress-dialog/

When I test my app on my phone all it does is Force Closes.
Can anybody help please?
Heres my .Java Activity:

```
public class XXXXXActivity extends Activity {
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    WebView myWebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this),"Android");
    WebSettings websettings =
            myWebView.getSettings();
    websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://XXXXX.com");
}

private void runDialog(final int seconds)
{
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...", "Loading...");
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
           try {
                        Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;
    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context*/
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    /** Show a toast from the web page*/
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url); 
        if
        (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("XXXXX.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent=new
                Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
[2012-04-13 19:44:55 - XXXXX] ------------------------------
[2012-04-13 19:44:55 - XXXXX] Android Launch!
[2012-04-13 19:44:55 - XXXXX] adb is running normally.
[2012-04-13 19:44:55 - XXXXX] No Launcher activity found!
[2012-04-13 19:44:55 - XXXXX] The launch will only sync the application package   on the device!
[2012-04-13 19:44:55 - XXXXX] Performing sync
[2012-04-13 19:44:55 - XXXXX] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'MY-PHONE' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2012-04-13 19:44:55 - XXXXX] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'MY-PHONE'
[2012-04-13 19:45:08 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error
[2012-04-13 19:45:08 - XXXXX] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-04-13 19:45:08 - XXXXX] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-04-13 19:46:05 - XXXXX] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'sync'!
```

Comment: please post your logcat output.

Answer (score 0):

I see one problem: you dismiss dialog in non-gui thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
           try {
                        Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

This code is very strange at all, I think you should rewrite logic at  all.

Comment: This shouldnt be the problem because he is not calling runDialog function anywhere in the code.

Comment: @AlexKlimashevsky Is it possible for you to find a link or something on what to rewrite the code as? As I said in my question, I am new to Android.

Comment: @SaneeshCS Do I need to call the runDialog function in the code? As I said in my question, I am new to Android. Also this is all the tutorial told me to do so I'm wondering if that guy left out something?

Comment: Can you please post your logcat output.

Comment: You have to call runDialog function if you want to display the progressbar. Before doing that, find out why are you getting the force close. Hope you have declared this activity in your manifest.

Comment: @SaneeshCS That is the problem then. The problem is I can't seem to find anything on declaring this activity in the manifest. Could you give me a hint? :)   Also my logcat says there was no launcher activity found, so I changed it to "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" and I still have the problem.